# How do I build and use an event so that I can listen to see if a file has been written to on any drive on my computer?

Tags: c#, events

I am working on learning C# events. I have some code below that has a couple of events built from a delegate AddNum. What I am trying to find out, and learn in the process, is how and when should an event be used.

I am new to this part of C# and am finding that when it comes to events I am not certain as to whether to make an event or to do my code some other way.

The code is simple below but it should give me the insight on how to build an Event which is were I think that i am a bit lost at the moment. What is an event really used for in the first place. I know that in a form application events are used for components to track the state of the button. Say on-click is an event but in a Console application how would I use and event.

Let me see. I have to narrow down the question.

I want to make a simple event handler from the code below that will send a message if a number is above, say 10 in the addition. I think this is where I might be missing something. In my simple example is there even a reason to have an event. Or are events more if you are listening for some thing. Lets say that I have a file out on a computer that logs grades every time that someone receives a grade that is greater than a 70 on an online quiz.

The event will listen for a logger writing to the grade file on say the Q drive on the network.

**Question: **So to make the question simple I am going to ask how to build an event so that I can detect if something has changed a file on my computer?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Delegate
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate void Writer(string m);
        public delegate int AddNum(int a, int b);

        static Logger logger = new Logger();
        static Writer writer = new Writer(logger.WriteMessage);
        static AddNum addme  = new AddNum(meTwo);

        static public event AddNum Ned;
        static public event AddNum SnowMan;
        static public event AddNum MotherGoose; 

        static private int meTwo(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            writer("Test");
            int temp = addme(4, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(temp);

            if (Ned != null)
            {
                Ned(4, 5);
                Writer("Some is changing a grade on your computer!");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Logger
    {
        public void WriteMessage(String m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can understand events as a signal sent from a sender to one or many receivers (the event handlers/listeners). While i see in your code that you fire/raise an Ned event, there are no event handlers registered/added to that event. If you say something but nobody listens, then well, nothing happens... ;)

Comment: Also, look at some event types provided by the .NET framework. The event delegates always define arguments in the form (sender, someEventArg). It is good practice to do it the same way for your event delegate types.

Comment: I think that question is to the point and asks a specific question

Comment: Please find updated answer for you changed in the question (EDIT 1)

Answer (score 2):

Events are used for weak linking from the source of the event to the consumer. Weak linking means that the source of the event does not really know or care about the type of object that is listening to the event and there might not even be any objects listening. This means, for example, a button does not have a direct reference to the event listeners (it sort of does but it is not strongly typed) and doesn't care. In some cases, this is correct and is a question of Object Oriented design.

In other cases, your object will need to "have" a particular reference (your example "has a" logger), in which case, your class can and should call directly onto the logger using a function to do something like LogEvent(). In a similar way, if your class inherits another class (an "is a" relationship - an apple "is a" fruit) then the apple by definition has a reference to the fruit's protected and public functions/data and can again call a function directly on it, it wouldn't be correct to fire an event into an object you already have a reference to.

It takes a while to make sense of these concepts and it is usually much easier to learn it from real-world applications since you can make an example, like the one above, do whatever you want without really understanding the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking:
"An event is a message sent by an object to signal the occurrence of an action. The action could be caused by user interaction, such as a mouse click, or it could be triggered by some other program logic. The object that raises (triggers) the event is called the event sender. The object that captures the event and responds to it is called the event receiver."

Simple example for your console and easy to implement: you got a logger class there . Let`s assume one application writes LogData on a harddisk.

In another application you could create a file watcher
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx. This is a predefined class with the purpose of watching your file system and raising an event if the logfile is changed. Then you can react to the event by loading the updated file and display some information in you console.

Of course you don`t need a predefined watcher class but it is an easy start.

To dig deeper look at some sites covering events/delegates, and make you confortable with raising and consuming of events:

Events and Delegates
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720047(v=vs.71).aspx
Provides an overview of the event model and describes delegates in the .NET Framework.

Consuming Events
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720052(v=vs.71).aspx
Provides an overview of how .NET Framework applications consume events.

Raising an Event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720442(v=vs.71).aspx
Shows how to provide event functionality in your class.

Answer (score 1):

***Notifications:***

Events are used when you what to signalize that something has happened, and you expect adequate reaction for the event. Examples: an error occurred, new item appeared in a queue, new file was created in a folder....

***Async pattern:***

Events are also useful for async processing, if you want to start long running job and notify all the subscribers about completing the job you can use [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Book Reference:**

To learn deeper about event you can always refer to the book: ["C# in Depth" by Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)

**EDIT 1:**

Answering for your updates, both you scenarios might be really useful. With you calculation example, let's say you might have a risk calculator and what to log calculation that is suspicious or might be wrong... In case of grading students, you may want to react somehow on exceptional results, to run some additional check procedure for them, or to log result, or for gathering some static data...

To look for changes in log file to make a crucial decision is not the best idea, it's better to do that on calculation stage. Here is an example for the grading case, you have mentioned:

```
public class GradingSystem
{
    private readonly Random _rnd = new Random();

    public event Action<ExamData, ExamResult> ExceptionalResultFound;
    public event Action<ExamData, ExamResult> ResultFound;

    protected virtual void RaiseResultFound(ExamData arg1, ExamResult arg2)
    {
        Action<ExamData, ExamResult> handler = ResultFound;

        if (handler != null) 
            handler(arg1, arg2);
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseExceptionalResultFound(ExamData arg1, ExamResult arg2)
    {
        var handler = ExceptionalResultFound;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(arg1, arg2);
    }

    //long running task  
    public void EvaluateAsync(ExamData data)
    {
        //some evaluation logic
        var result = new ExamResult {Grade = 100 - _rnd.Next(100)};
        if (result.Grade > 95)
            RaiseExceptionalResultFound(data, result);

        RaiseResultFound(data, result);
    }
}

public class ExamResult
{
    public decimal Grade { get; set; }
}

public class ExamData
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

And usage:

```
private static void OnExceptionResult(ExamData data, ExamResult result)
{
    //save the result, send notification, log results...
    Console.WriteLine(@"Student: {0} achieve score: {1}", data.StudentName, result.Grade);
}

private static void OnResult(ExamData data, ExamResult result)
{
    //save results
    //Console.WriteLine(@"Student: {0} achieve score: {1}", data.StudentName, result.Grade);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var gradingSystem = new GradingSystem();
    gradingSystem.ExceptionalResultFound += OnExceptionResult;
    gradingSystem.ResultFound+= OnResult;

    for (var i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        gradingSystem.EvaluateAsync(new ExamData {StudentName = String.Format("Student #{0}", i)});
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Example:**

Here is an example  how to organize console reader, notifying about entered commands from console (of course it's only for the sake of an example):

*Listener*

```
public class ConsoleReader
{
    public event Action<string> OnCommandEntered;
    public event Action OnQuit;

    private void RaiseOnQuit()
    {
        Action handler = OnQuit;

        if (handler != null) 
            handler();
    }

    private void RaiseOnCommandEntered(string command)
    {
        Action<string> handler = OnCommandEntered;

        if (handler != null) 
            handler(command);
    }

    public void StartReading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var command = Console.ReadLine();

            if (String.Equals(command, "quit"))
            {
                RaiseOnQuit();
                return;
            }

            RaiseOnCommandEntered(command);
        }
    }
}
```

*And the usage:*

```
internal class Program
{

    private static void OnExit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting from app");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void OnCommand(string command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Command {0} entered", command);
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new ConsoleReader();
        listener.OnQuit += OnExit;
        listener.OnCommandEntered += OnCommand;

        listener.StartReading();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your sample code, you have confused the role of the "listener" and the "sender". The `OnXXX` methods in your *Program* class are event handlers, hence you can say that *Program* listens to the events offered by *ConsoleListener*. On the other side, *ConsoleListener* actually provides the events and raises them, which makes it a sender and not a listener. Since the OP is unaccustomed with events, i think it is important to avoid confusion there. (I know what you meant by chosing the name "ConsoleListener", but it really invites misunderstanding when speaking about events.)

Comment: Agree, some people might be confused a bit. Listener was because it listens everything from console, every new line entered :). Renamed it to Reader to avoid confusing.